# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pip._internal.commands.install'

Tags: python, pip, exe, command-prompt, yolov5

I was getting the following error when trying to run the detect.py file as an executable file from the command prompt. Can anybody help?
Specifically speaking, this is the detect.py file from yolov5.

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "detect.py", line 39, in <module>
  File "pip\_internal\__init__.py", line 19, in main
    # TODO
  File "pip\_internal\utils\entrypoints.py", line 43, in _wrapper
  File "pip\_internal\cli\main.py", line 68, in main
  File "pip\_internal\commands\__init__.py", line 109, in create_command
    raise ImportError('OpenCV loader: missing configuration file: {}. Check OpenCV installation.'.format(fnames))
  File "importlib\__init__.py", line 127, in import_module
    applySysPathWorkaround = True
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1006, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 983, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 965, in _find_and_load_unlocked
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pip._internal.commands.install'
[10908] Failed to execute script 'detect' due to unhandled exception!
```

Comment: This is the error:  `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pip._internal.commands.install'`    beyond this you would need to show the code so users can help you:   https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: update your pip version  ```python -m pip install --upgrade pip```

Comment: got the following result:                    Requirement already satisfied: pip in c:\users\pande\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\lib\site-packages (22.1.2)

Comment: error still remains